# Corresponding GCMRegistrar.isRegistered() in new GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement GCM using the new **GoogleCloudMessaging API**.

I want to check whether the device is registered on the cloud, which was previously checked using **GCMRegistrar.isRegistered()**.

Is there any way I can achieve this check using the new API?
**EDIT:** I know I can save the registeration Id in my app, but I want to know the status of my device on the cloud - whether it is registered or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deprecated `GCMRegistrar` was just a helper client class that stored the RegistrationID locally on the device. `GCMRegistrar.isRegistered()` never called the GCM server to find if the device is registered (since there is no such API). It just checked if a previously received RegistrationID is locally stored on the device for a specific app (and invalidated the stored RegistrationId on some occassions, such as when the app version changes).

In fact, you can see the code of GCMRegistrar [here](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java?r=87275a7eaab265c60b17f178b0c5cdd2983dc686):

```
/**
 * Gets the current registration id for application on GCM service.
 * <p>
 * If result is empty, the registration has failed.
 *
 * @return registration id, or empty string if the registration is not
 *         complete.
 */
public static String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    // check if app was updated; if so, it must clear registration id to
    // avoid a race condition if GCM sends a message
    int oldVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int newVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (oldVersion != Integer.MIN_VALUE && oldVersion != newVersion) {
        Log.v(TAG, "App version changed from " + oldVersion + " to " +
                newVersion + "; resetting registration id");
        clearRegistrationId(context);
        registrationId = "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the application was successfully registered on GCM
 * service.
 */
public static boolean isRegistered(Context context) {
    return getRegistrationId(context).length() > 0;
}
```

Therefore, if you store the registration ID in your app, you would achieve the exact same functionality you had when you used `GCMRegistrar`. The only way to know for sure in the client app that the device is registered or not registered to GCM is to call `GoogleCloudMessaging.register` or `GoogleCloudMessaging.unregister`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
String SENDER_ID = "13312313";//product id will be different for you
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
Context context =getApplicationContext();
String regid;

String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid =   gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                    msg = regid;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg=null;
                }
```

save to sharedpreferences

```
private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);

        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);

        editor.commit();
    }
```

Now check for exixtence

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(registrationId)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return null;
        }

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For your concern U can check registration status and much more like this

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your registration ID : " +
        // registrationId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM"
                + registrationId);
        //Log.d("NAME", LoginActivity.email);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, LoginActivity.uid,
                LoginActivity.phone, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context,
                getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     * This message wil be notified at status bar!!!
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
        // context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is the old, deprecated, interface and in any case the methods listed are all callbacks not directly invokable by the user.